# How to select 2 or more models back in a where clause

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, where-clause

In SQL you can have `SELECT x,y FROM ...`

but if I use `where`, the sql generated will only select from the models which it is acting upon.

So for example:

```
user has_many :posts
post belongs_to :user
```

`Post.includes(:users).where('created_at < ?' 1.day.ago`) will have

```
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (created_at > '2013-03-06 07:37:09.010916')
```

but how do I `SELECT` the post and the users so it will return the posts users as well?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: As Saurabh pointed out, the loaded association should be :user and not :users

Includes is used to eager load association records, meaning that given the following

```
@posts = Post.includes(:user)
@posts.each do |post|
  post.user
end
```

Only 2 queries will be made to the database, one for fetching the posts and another for fetching all the users that is associated to `@posts`.  Rails manages the associations for you. Simple.

If you want to get a certain column value from a different table, try the following

```
@posts = Post.joins(:user).select('posts.*, users.name AS user_name')
@posts.first.user_name # will give you the name of the first user associated to the post
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**, your associations are wrong. You can't do `Post.includes(:users)` when you say: `post belongs_to :user`.

The correct way is -

`Post.includes(:user)` for the **belongs_to associations**.

**Second**, you can select a value from different table by doing so:

```
Post.includes(:user).where(:user => {:name => params[:name]})
```

The above query will give you all the posts whose user name is `params[:name]` where `:name` is the field from the user table.